# Remove first character if it is comma using array also

Tags: java, arrays

I have wrote a code, It has string consist email addresses, and I am going to put it into array but always I am getting `,` (comma). Here is my code:

```
 String getEmail = "abeywicrema@gmail.com,shan.a@jinasena.com.lk,yasasjayanga@gmail.com";
        String[] srr = getEmail.split(",");
        //String tsd = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < srr.length; i++) {
            String string = srr[i];

            String[] getEmailList = {",\"" + string + "\""};

            System.out.print(getEmailList[0]);
        }
```

This is my output

**,"abeywicrema@gmail.com","shan.a@jinasena.com.lk","yasasjayanga@gmail.com"**

Comma comes in first, I need to remove this first comma, please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Because you are adding comma prefix in `String[] getEmailList = {",\"" + string + "\""};`.

Answer (score 0):

> Simply one line statement ( replace all commas with surrounding double quotes )

```
String getEmail = "abeywicrema@gmail.com,shan.a@jinasena.com.lk,yasasjayanga@gmail.com";
System.out.println("\""+getEmail.replaceAll(",", "\",\"")+"\"");
```

---

OR This will solve your problem. Use `StringBuilder` to combine the strings.

```
String getEmail = "abeywicrema@gmail.com,shan.a@jinasena.com.lk,yasasjayanga@gmail.com";
String[] srr = getEmail.split(",");

StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < srr.length; i++) {
    String string = srr[i];

    str1.append(",\"" + string + "\"");
}

System.out.println(str1.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need `String[]` to hold the email as a `String`, it's enough in your case to have a `String` instead. So `getEmailList` should be of type `String`.

Second, you should reconsider your variable's names. `getEmailList` is a suitable name for a *method* and not a variable, I suggest for example simply using `currentEmail` or something like that.

Last, to remove the first comma, use [`Sting#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) or (better solution), when you print for the first time, simply don't print the comma and add it only in the iterations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment I will use standards.

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem i guess, but i really don't see a point of using string array to do that

```
String getEmail = "abeywicrema@gmail.com,shan.a@jinasena.com.lk,yasasjayanga@gmail.com";
        String[] srr = getEmail.split(",");
        //String tsd = "";
        int track = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < srr.length; i++) {
            String string = srr[i];
            if (track == 0){
                String[] getEmailList = {"\"" + string + "\""};
                track = track + 1;
            }else{
                String[] getEmailList = {",\"" + string + "\""};
            }

            System.out.print(getEmailList[0]);
        }
```